# meaning of Static NSMutableArray and multi thread usage

Tags: objective-c

what exactly `static` do in following codes and when should I or  better use `Static` :

```
// Returns an array of 30 odd numbers
- (NSArray *)odds
{
static NSMutableArray *odds;
odds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int i = 1;
while ([odds count] < 30) {
[odds addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
i += 2;
}
return odds;
}
```

Comment: Maybe a quick search on the web before asking? [Wikipedia "static (keyword)"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword))

Comment: We cannot explain that code because it does not compile: *"initializer element is not a compile-time constant"*.

Comment: @MartinR compile error fixed

Comment: Your static is pointless here.. The point Of a static is that it is allocated once, but you're method I initialises it every time.

Comment: It really helps to learn the "C" language, there are many books available. Note that the `static` keyword has different meaning depending where it is used.

Comment: @MartinR  what I searched in different recourses and other questions were confusing, thanX to dear MartinR , the answer was clear and useful

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code in your question was originally

```
- (NSArray *)odds
{
    static NSMutableArray *odds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // ... fill array ...
    return odds;
}
```

and you said in a (now deleted) comment that you found that code in a Big Nerd Ranch Guide.

Well, that guide has an error then.

A static local variable exists for the lifetime of the program, but is only visible 
inside the function where it is declared. The value of the variable is retained between
repeated function calls.

In C and Objective-C, a static local variable can only be initialized with a compile-time
constant, therefore

```
static NSMutableArray *odds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

is *invalid*. (Btw, that restriction does not exist in C++. Therefore the above code is *valid* in Objective-C++, although pointless.)

So how to fix this? **Method 1:** (The simplest solution.) Drop the `static`:

```
- (NSArray *)odds
{
    NSMutableArray *odds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    // ... fill array ...
    return odds;
}
```

Now `odds` is a normal local variable, and the array is created and filled each time
when the function is called.

**Method 2:** A static variable can be used to create and fill the array only once, when the method is called the first time. 
That would look like:

```
- (NSArray *)odds
{
    static NSMutableArray *odds = nil;
    if (odds == nil) { // Check if array has already been initialized or not.
        odds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // ... fill array ...
    }
    return odds;
}
```

The function "remembers" the value of the variable, so when the function is called the
second time, it returns the existing array and does not create a new one.

**Method 3:** The "modern" way to initialize something only once is to use the GCD function `dispatch_once()`:

```
- (NSArray *)odds
{
    static NSMutableArray *odds;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        odds = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // ... fill array ...
    });
    return odds;
}
```

This has the additional advantage of being thread-safe.

Comment: thanx martin, it was perfect and complete like any other of your answers.

Comment: @Hadi You'll want to use the code in my answer (but leave Martin's as accepted as his answer is far more complete -- mine is more of a comment on that).

Answer (score 3):

What Martin said (in #3), but with a bit more pedantry:

```
- (NSArray *)odds
{
    static NSArray *odds;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // ... fill temp ...
        odds = [temp copy];
    });
    return odds;
}
```

By creating an immutable copy of that mutable array here, it means any caller that calls `copy` will get that copy for free (well, cost of bumping the retain count) whereas copying a mutable array is (relatively) expensive.    It also hardens the code against a bug where a caller mutates the returned array.  Should never happen, but does.