# static NSDictionary* const letterValues = @{ ..... } in a method does not compile

Tags: ios, objective-c, static, nsdictionary, constants

In [a word game for iPhone](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/tree/master/ScrollContent):

[image: app screenshot]

I'm trying to use the following code in my custom view [Tile.m](https://github.com/afarber/ios-newbie/blob/master/ScrollContent/ScrollContent/Tile.m):

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    static NSDictionary* const letterValues = @{
                                         @"A": @1,
                                         @"B": @4,
                                         @"C": @4,
                                         // ...
                                         @"X": @8,
                                         @"Y": @3,
                                         @"Z": @10,
                                         };

    NSString* randomLetter = [kLetters substringWithRange:[kLetters rangeOfComposedCharacterSequenceAtIndex:arc4random_uniform(kLetters.length)]];
    int letterValue = [letterValues[randomLetter] integerValue];

    _smallLetter.text = _bigLetter.text = randomLetter;
    _smallValue.text = _bigValue.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", letterValue];
}
```

Unfortunately this gives me compile error **Initializer element is not a compile-time constant** and I have to remove the `static` keyword to get my app compile in Xcode (here [fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR1s7.png)):

[image: Xcode screenshot]

I think I initialize the `NSDictionary` correctly - by using the new [Objective-C Literals](http://blog.bignerdranch.com/398-objective-c-literals-part-1/) syntax.

But why can't I use `static` here?

I thought it would be appropriate here to make sure that my `letterValues` constant is set only once?

Comment: move it out from class

Comment: Moving it out from class results in same compile-time error

Comment: @Btw., that code is *valid* and works in Objective-C++ :-)

Comment: Which code is valid (the code in my question doesn't compile in Xcode 5.1) and what do you mean by Objective-**C++**?

Comment: @AlexanderFarber: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684112/what-is-objective-c - Objective-C++ is the "combination" of Objective-C with C++ (and is poorly documented). Objective-C++ files have the extension .mm. Your code should compile if you rename the file to "Tile.mm", because C++ has different rules for static initializers. - But this was just meant as a remark, not as *the* solution. - You can also have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21365532/meaning-of-static-nsmutablearray-and-multi-thread-usage, which is a different question with a similar answer.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can only set a static variable during initialization with a constant. @{} creates an object, thus not a constant.

Do this instead:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    static NSDictionary* letterValues = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        letterValues = @{
          @"A": @1,
          @"B": @4,
          @"C": @4,
          // ...
          @"X": @8,
          @"Y": @3,
          @"Z": @10,
          };
    });


    ...
}
```

Some other answers here suggest a check for nil instead of dispatch once, but that can cause issues when creating multiple tiles at the same time (via threads). dispatch_once implements the required locking.

Comment: Using `dispatch_once` is the best and safest way to initialize this kind of data objects. This is the most correct answer here.

Answer (score 5):

You can use static, but the assignment can't be made on the same line. Try this:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    static NSDictionary* letterValues = nil;
    if (!letterValues) {
        letterValues = @{@"A": @1,
                         @"B": @4,
                         @"C": @4,
                         // ...
                         @"X": @8,
                         @"Y": @3,
                         @"Z": @10};
    }
    ...
}
```

The reason is that the `@{<key> : <value>}` syntax is translated by the compiler into an Objective-C method (`[[NSPlaceholderDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]`), which cannot be resolved at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative is using the Macro Approach:

## Macro (The Easiest) Approach (2021)

```
#define kScreenNames @{ \
        @"HOME":                     @"Home Page", \
        @"SEARCH":                   @"Search Page", \
        @"MYLISTS":                  @"My List", \
        @"MYACCOUNT":                @"My Aaccount" \
}
```

it's short and elegant.

Then, you can use it like any other NSDictionary.

I hope this will help someone on the planet.

Best

Answer (score 3):

`NSDictionary` objects can't be created at compile time. However, if you need a static object, you can create one. You can, for example, use the `initialize` method, like this:

```
static NSDictionary* letterValues;

+ (void)initialize
{
    if (self == [MyClass class]) {
        letterValues = @{
                         @"A": @1,
                         @"B": @4,
                         @"C": @4,
                         @"X": @8,
                         @"Y": @3,
                         @"Z": @10,
                         };
    }
}
```

The if statement is there to prevent multiple calls of your code in `MyClass` subclasses.

Comment: wouldn't `+ (void)load` be more appropriate?

Comment: @dwery It really depends on your use case. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13326435/730701) to find out more about the difference between `load` and `initialize`.

Answer (score 2):

If you support iOS 14 (and its year-aligned releases) or later, you can now do this, assuming your keys are `NSString`s. This is because [Xcode 13 supports](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes#New-Features) Clang's `-fobjc-constant-literals` flag, which is on by default.